# Asp.net core Custom routing

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-routing, asp.net-core-1.0

I am trying to implement custom routing on an asp.net core application.

The desired result is the following:

http://Site_URL/MyController/Action/{Entity_SEO_Name}/

Entity_SEO_Name parameter will be a unique value saved into the database that it is going to help me identify the id of the entity that I am trying to display.

In order to achieve that I have implemented a custom route:

```
routes.MapMyCustomRoute(
            name: "DoctorDetails",
            template: "       {controller=MyController}/{action=TestRoute}/{name?}");


 public class MyTemplateRoute : TemplateRoute
 {
     public override async Task RouteAsync(RouteContext context)
    {
        //context.RouteData.Values are always empty. Here is the problem.
        var seo_name = context.RouteData.Values["Entity_SEO_Name"];

        int entityId = 0;
        if (seo_name != null)
        {
            entityId = GetEntityIdFromDB(seo_name);
        }
        //Here i need to have the id and pass it to controller
        context.RouteData.Values["id"] = entityId;
        await base.RouteAsync(context);
    }
}
```

My controller actionresult:

```
  public ActionResult TestRoute(int id)
  {
       var entity = GetEntityById(id);
            return Content("");
  }
```

The problem with this approach is that the context.RouteData.Values are always empty. 
Any ideas on how to move forward with this one ?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution too complicated. You can have route template like

```
template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{seo?}"
```

and controller action just like

```
public ActionResult TestRoute(string seo)
{
    var entity = GetEntityBySeo(seo);
    return Content("");
}
```

It is enough, asp.net mvc is smart enough to bind seo variable to the parameter from url path.